# How to make discord bot wait for reply for 5 minutes and then send a message? Using discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am using Discord js to make a discord bot. The role of the bot is to send a message to user in personal messages and then wait for user response for 5 minutes. If user does not sends anything back to the member then a message is send by the bot that there request has been denied because they did not send any email id. I am using discord.js collector npm package for taking message and sending it to the user. The problem I am getting is that the bot send back a reply to the user just after 30 seconds if user does not types anything. I don't want that. I wish the bot to wait for 5 mins before sending request denied message. Here is what my code looks like.

```
 message.reply("Please check your DM to verify your email id");
                const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                
                    const botMessage = await message.author.send("Enter your registered email Id please?");
                    const userMessage = await MessageCollector.asyncQuestion({
                      botMessage,
                      user: message.author.id,
                      time:300000 // milliseconds
                    }).catch(()=>{
                      message.author.send("Request Denied because you did not responded with a registerd email ID. You can request again!");
                      return 0;
                    });
```

I have also used discord js library to implement there own parameters such as idle but I am still getting the error. Here is what my code looks there.

```
message.reply("Please check your DM to verify your email id");
                    const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                    
                        const botMessage = await message.author.send("Enter your registered email Id please?");
                        const userMessage = await MessageCollector.asyncQuestion({
                          botMessage,
                          user: message.author.id,
                          idle:300000 // milliseconds
                        }).catch(()=>{
                          message.author.send("Request Denied because you did not responded with a registerd email ID. You can request again!");
                          return 0;
                        });
```

Would be great if someone could tell me where I am making a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [asyncQuestion](https://idjinn.github.io/Discord.js-Collector/MessageCollector.html#.asyncQuestion) function you're using doesn't have the time or idle properties.
Instead it has the collectorOptions which type is [MessageCollectorOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageCollectorOptions).

So what you should do is use the collectorOptions that the asyncQuestion defined and pass in an object with your time option, then your timer should work as intended.

```
const userMessage = await MessageCollector.asyncQuestion({
                    botMessage,
                    user: message.author.id,
                    collectorOptions: { time: 300000 }
                }).catch(() => {
                    // catch code here...
                });
```